# Youtube "Invalid category filter" API error

Tags: php, api, youtube

I am trying to create a Youtube RSS feed for the most popular videos for a given category, using the demo API page:
https://gdata.youtube.com/demo/index.html

This works just fine with one of their standard API calls:
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/standardfeeds/most_viewed?alt=rss&time=today

However, as soon as I add a category to it, I get a 400 error ("Invalid category filter"):
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/base/standardfeeds/most_viewed/-/{http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat}Music?alt=rss&time=today

I have tried urlencoding it, urlencoding just the last part, encoding just the curly brackets... but can't seem to get it to work.

Any solutions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Show some of the code you tried

Comment: I was just loading these into my browser - although I got exactly the same problem trying to collect them through Magpie RSS reader for PHP

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just worked it out - If you click on the 'edit URI before submitting' check box, it provides an encoded version of the URI which *does* work.